# How to connect to Internet with USB stick & How to open C Drive, D Drive & E Drive

Tags: usb, internet

There are no existing Questions which have an answer to this question.

Currently I'm using a USB stick to connect to the Internet, in my old computer. I was using Windows 7 (but since upgraded to Windows 10) when I first used it and all I needed to do was plug the stick into the USB port and the Console-Site-specific browser self loaded, which also provided a shortcut on the desktop to open the Console-Site-specific browser. I need the Console-Site-specific browser to load the connection details into, each time I buy a connection.

I have successfully installed Ubuntu into my new computer, and am browsing all of the features. I have plugged the USB stick into the laptop and received a message saying similar to that I'm now connected to the Internet, despite that not being possible because there was no current connection, however I can not find where the Console-Site-specific browser is loaded.

The only likely place in the Launcher appears to be Ubuntu Software.

In Ubuntu Desktop Guide - Install additional software - there is reference to "Software" which I assume is a program to install software but I can not find how to use that. It appears Ubuntu assumes the only place users obtain programs is from the Internet, but I want to transfer programs and data from my old computer.

I have purchased a new laptop and chosen Ubuntu, but now at a standstill because I can't connect to the Internet.

If I knew how to open, copy and or paste and or install into, C Drive, D Drive & E Drive, I could probably resolve my problems.

I also have a text editor which I want to install.

And I want to install XAMPP which requires being installed into C Drive.

I have been told Ubuntu includes the latest version of PHP, but I don't know if it includes any other parts of XAMPP.

Can somebody help please?

UPDATE

The "Console-Site-specific browser", including the exe file, is located in C:\Program Files. I can copy that onto a DVD, likewise with the Text Editor. But what do I do with them on the DVD in Ubuntu? The "Console-Site-specific browser", and the Text Editor, probably will not support Ubuntu, so it appears I'm doomed. The Internet connections in the country I'm in, is not good. Another ISP probably will not support Ubuntu as 99% of new computers for sale here come with Windows 10 so the likelihood of Ubuntu being supported by any ISP is very low. I do not know how to find the web address, and I guess for obvious reasons that will be well hidden.

If I can't connect to the Internet I'll need to abandon Ubuntu. Another web developer spoke so highly of Ubuntu, but he probably uses Windows to connect to the Internet.

I was expecting Ubuntu to make everything interchangeable with Windows programs, the same as most programs are interchangeable with Windows & Mac, but it appears my expectations were too high. I recall something in the spreadsheet within Ubuntu being compatible with outside programs.

Also with the website I intend building, I was intending to encourage users to change to Ubuntu, but that idea now appears doomed.

Is there any other Linux OS that is compatible with Windows programs?

UPDATE

Maybe "Wine" is the solution, but when I search in Ubuntu Software "No Application Found".

How do I install Wine?

Maybe download from my old laptop and burn it onto a DVD, but I'm bewildered if I can't open the DVD Drive.

Comment: What is "consul"?

Comment: Consul = Site-specific browser

Comment: I think the word should have been "console".

Comment: As you might now, the programs for Windows do not work on Linux (two different operating systems, not just a better face over the same old stuff). In Linux there is no such a thing as "C, D, E, ..." drives. There are partitions, mountpoints, and such. You have to format at least one partition to install the operating system with a decent file system (no FAT, no NTFS...). For the connection, does the provider support Linux? If not, you are probably doomed (you need a proprietary browser to access it, right? If they do not support Linux, we cannot do anything...).

Comment: I strongly suggest that you read the (community) guides on how to switch from another OS to Ubuntu https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwitchingToUbuntu , in particular the one about Windows https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwitchingToUbuntu/FromWindows

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu is not Windows. If you try and do things the same way as in Windows, you will be frustrated.

There is no such thing as a C: drive (or E: drive or...). There are only mountpoints. Like, if you have a USB called 'MYUSB', its contents will be accessible (after mounting, which is done when you click it in the file manager - or you can configure it to auto-mount disks) at the `/media/USERNAME/MYUSB/` directory.

The equivalent to Windows "installers" are Debian Packages (file format `.deb`). Ubuntu has a very intuitive software installation system - no click-click-click installers, no hunting the web for apps - just search for its name in Software and click 'Install'.

If you want to access your Windows drives from Ubuntu, just click on the button named `XX-GB Volume` in the side panel.

XAMPP consists of Apache, MySQL, PHP and Perl. Perl comes installed, you can install the rest with the command

```
sudo apt-get install apache2 mysql-server php7.0
```

Also, Ubuntu automatically decides the place for installed programs.

As for the internet... That'll have to be a separate question - please provide all details about the modem and the "Console-Site-specific browser". If you can see what web address the "Console-Site-specific browser" access upon clicking the shortcut, just visiting there in Ubuntu (and logging in, whatever else) will (most probably) work.